# counter randomly resets on page refresh not sure why? [heroku/ python]

Tags: python-2.7, heroku, flask

So right now I have a global counter variable. And it updates whenever a message is sent. Running my program locally I get no weirdness, but on heroku, sometimes the variable just bumps down to zero if I reload the page. Reload it again, its back to a number.

I don't know why that is happening. It only happens on heroku. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

https://github.com/sharkwheels/sendCatsWeb/blob/master/app.py

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `counter` variable is running in-memory only.

What this means is that if your Python process stops running (restarts, crashes, whatever) -- the next time this web server boots up, that counter will be reset back to `0` (the default value).

When you run any programs on Heroku, they will restart frequently. This happens randomly, and for many reasons:

- Maybe Heroku had to move your application to another web server due to load issues.
- Maybe your process crashes, and Heroku restarted it.
- Maybe Heroku created another instance of your web app to handle increased load.

This stuff can happen for many reasons.

Regardless -- you should NEVER expect Heroku to run your webapp continuously. Always expect your process to be restarted. This is a best practice in the web development community.

Your application should ideally function something like this:

- When visitors visit your page, you send an increment request to a database counter of some sort that is persisted permanently in some form of database.

This way, regardless of how often your web application reboots, your data is never lost.

Comment: Ah ok. i didn't think about that, re: memory. Makes a lot more sense now. I was hoping to not have to deal w/ a database as its just one variable, but guess I'll have to set one up. Thanks!